# Tile-Overlay Animation - Bing / Google

Tags: javascript, google-maps, tiles, bing-maps

I've created a tile set, and this tile set expires every 10 mins.  However I want to be able to show a cycle of the past 50 mins (of stored tiles i have).

I know with Google Maps 2.0 you can do this with toggling the map tiles on / off, however google 3.0 (since it's mobilized) doesn't seem to have a real clean way of doing this that I've found so far.

Is there a good way to do it with either google 3 or bing that you've seen/used?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely because that tiles are cached. Try appending a timestamp to end of the tile's url. When you want to change the tiles, update the timestamp then turn the layer off then on. I have updated google v2/v3 and bing 6.2 tile overlays in this manner without any issues.

Comment: did this.. google 3.0 has a very 'blinked' look when you're just toggling on and off. It's not a matter of caching more a matter of using the correct items.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue was. Were you just not using the appropriate MVCArray functions?